# xcode passing pointers to a method

Tags: objective-c, pointers

My knowledge of code just doesn't go this deep, and I have no idea where to look.

```
- (void) testResult: (Float32 *) levels lightLevel: (Float32 *) lightLevel;
```

It is required that the levels and lightLevel data pointers passed to this method point to pre-allocated storage holding any array of 2 Float32 values.

How would I retrieve these values?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Float32 levels[2];
Float32 lightLevel[2];
[mysteryObject testResult:levels lightLevel:lightlevel];
```

Comment: Perfect.  Thank you so much.  It's exactly what I needed to see.